# Transport of objects in Hana Cloud

Tags: hana

I created several objects in Hana Cloud (stored procedures, table types, etc)
I don't know how to transport these objects from DEV space to PROD space as the architect doesn't allow the following commands  directly in PROD space :

CREATE PROCEDURE.....
Can somebody suggest how objects of Hana Cloud can be transported.

Thanks